# How to change the enumeration of \subpart in exam document class?

Tags: formatting, exam

By default, `\subpart` uses `i.` , `ii.` , etc. I would like to change it to `(i)`,`(ii)`,etc. How do I do that?

Comment: Could you provide us with a working document so we can help you more readily? It's not all that great to generate something like that from scratch. *You* are in the best position to help us help you. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can redefine the `\thesubpart`

```
\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{(\roman{subpart})}
```

The dot after the label can be removed by

```
\renewcommand{\subpartlabel}{\thesubpart}   %% to remove the dot
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{(\roman{subpart})}
\renewcommand{\subpartlabel}{\thesubpart}   %% to remove the dot
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question How are you?
\begin{parts}
    \part ...
    \begin{subparts}
    \subpart ...
    \subpart ...
    \subpart ...
    \end{subparts}
    \part ...
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more details, read page 39 of `exam` manual.