# problem with enumeration of \subpart and Spanish characters in exam document class?

Tags: exam, spanish

maybe this is a silly question but I am stuck. When I was trying to change the \subpart enumeration in the exam class from i,ii,iii to (i), (ii), (iii) it worked with the MWE that I am including

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241670/how-to-change-the- 
enumeration-of-subpart-in-exam-document-class
\documentclass[11pt, spanish]{exam}
%\documentclass{exam}
%caracteres en español
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{(\roman{subpart})}
\renewcommand{\subpartlabel}{\thesubpart}   %% to remove the dot
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question ¿Hola cómo estás?
   \begin{parts}
   \part ...
    \begin{subparts}
     \subpart ... Hola ¿qué haces?
     \subpart ...
     \subpart ...
   \end{subparts}
  \part ...
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

but when I am trying to change the language to spanish the \subparts change again to Uppercase (I), (II), etc. Only works in english. I have been trying with UTF and ANSI and does not work. Please help, I do not know what I am doing wrong, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `spanish.ldf` redefines the command `\@roman`, which is used by the command `\roman`.  The fix is to avoid using `\roman` and instead use the TeX command `\romannumeral`, as in

```
 \renewcommand{\thesubpart}{(\romannumeral \value{subpart})}
```